# how to send data in both directions using an interface between Activity and Fragment

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments

i made an interface in the fragment class kind of like a listener to send a string from the Fragment to the Activity.   what is the best way to also send strings in the opposite direction? from activity to fragment?  so there is now an interface in the fragment, so do i have to make another interface in the Activity to send strings in the other direction, or is there a better way?

the fragment class:

```
 public class FragmentHeadless extends Activity implements FragmentHeadlessFragment.OnTimeRequestedListener {

FragmentTransaction transaction;
Button button;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_headless);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(new FragmentHeadlessFragment(), "processorFragment");
        transaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void passString(String stringFromFragment) {
     textView.setText(stringFromFragment);
     Toast.makeText(this, "String passed from fragment " + stringFromFragment, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

 }
```

the activity class

```
 public class FragmentHeadlessFragment extends Fragment {

private OnTimeRequestedListener listener;
String tempString = "";
Activity activity;
Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    handler = new Handler();

    new Thread(){

        public void run() {

        SystemClock.sleep(3000);

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                 // pass string to activity
              passData("test string from fragment with 3 second delay");


            }
         });

         } // end run

  }.start(); 

} // end onCreate

 @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if (activity instanceof OnTimeRequestedListener) {
      listener = (OnTimeRequestedListener) activity;
    } else {
      throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
          + " must implemenet OnTimeRequestedListener");
    }
  }

@Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  activity = getActivity();
  setRetainInstance(true);


 }

 public interface OnTimeRequestedListener {
        public void passString(String timeNumberString);

  }

 public void passData(String data) {
        listener.passString(data);
    }



 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you have an instance to the fragment, you can just call the function you need via the activitiy:

instead of :

```
transaction.add(new FragmentHeadlessFragment(), "processorFragment");
```

use:

```
private FragmentHeadlessFragment mFragment;
...
mFragment=new FragmentHeadlessFragment();
transaction.add(mFragment, "processorFragment");
```

and when you wish, call:

```
mFragment.foo(myInt,myString,...) ;
```

btw, why do you have a field for the transaction?

Comment: i don't know why i have a field for Transaction.   I guess it is better not to have that in a field?

Comment: thank you for your help, i tried out this code and it works great, now I know another way to send info between fragment and activity